# How can I read a large CSV file into Python with speed?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, dask

I'm trying to load a ~67 gb dataframe (6,000,000 features by 2300 rows) into dask for machine learning. I'm using a 96 core machine on AWS that I wish to utilize for the actual machine learning bit. However, Dask loads CSVs in a single thread. It has already taken a full 24 hours and it hasn't loaded.

```
#I tried to display a progress bar, but it is not implemented on dask's load_csv
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
pbar = ProgressBar()
pbar.register()

df = dd.read_csv('../Larger_than_the_average_CSV.csv')
```

Is there a faster way to load this into Dask and make it persistent? Should I switch to a different technology (Spark on Scala or PySpark?)

Dask is probably still loading it as I can see a steady 100% CPU utilization in `top`.

Comment: are you reading from S3 path? If yes then spark will give better performance.

Comment: @RamdevSharma It is just CSV stored on the instance's storage. Do you think moving it to s3 will increase performance?

Comment: No.  Local on an EC2's EBS volume will be far faster than S3.

Comment: In you case, you are using single m/c so S3 will not help but spark will surely help by running in local mode with higher count of executors.

Comment: @RamdevSharma How would you go about doing this? I've never used spark before.

Comment: The problem here is that you are loading a single file. My suggestion will be to nicely partition the data in different files

Comment: @user32185 I can do that. Let's say I partition it into 6 different ~10GB files. How would you train a random forest iteratively on the data?

Answer (score 0):

The code you show in the question probably takes no time at all, because you are not actually loading anything, just setting up the job prescription. How long this takes will depend on the chunksize you specify.

There are two main bottlenecks to consider for actual loading:

- getting the data from disc into memory, raw data transfer over a single disc interface,
- parsing that data into in-memory stuff

There is not much you can do about the former if you are on a local disc, and you would expect it to be a small fraction.

The latter may suffer from the GIL, even though dask will execute in multiple threads by default (which is why it may appear only one thread is being used). You would do well to read the dask documentation about the different schedulers, and should try using the Distributed scheduler, even though you are on a single machine, with a mix of threads and processes.

Finally, you probably don't want to "load" the data at all, but process it. Yes, you can persist into memory with Dask if you wish (`dask.persist`, funnily), but please do not use many workers to load the data just so you then make it into a Pandas dataframe in your client process memory.

Comment: quite sure that `dd.read_csv` does read the entire csv into a dask dataframe. From my understanding, it is not a mapped task, but a conversion of a csv into a partitioned set of pandas dfs. Once it reads, I'd like to do some preprocessing and then run a random forest on the data.

Comment: Nope, `dd.read_csv` only reads metadata and gives you a lazy pointer to the data. In this respect it is the same as spark's version.

Comment: hmmm....if it doesn't read the data at all, why then does it take so long? I've got other code that would tell me if this finishes.

Comment: It *does* need to find line-ending delimiters throughout the file. Try setting your blocksize (much) larger.

Comment: It is at the default value right now (64 Mb). How would you determine the ideal blocksize?

Comment: There is no ideal, but you'll have 76GB / 64Mb = 1050 parts, and as many delimiter searches going on. You could easily go a factor of 10 and still saturate all of your cores.

Comment: Ok thanks! Is `read_csv` supposed to be multi threaded? It runs on one thread for me.

Comment: Again... finding out the metadata (columns, start-stop byte ranges) happens in the client; loading and processing the data happens in threads and/or processes.